# Android change TextField outline/boarder color

Tags: android, textfield

I have a text field, and on Android 2.2, when it is in focus or being used, it highlights it and puts an **orange** boarder around it.

The orange really doesn't look good with the other colors in my app, so I am wondering if there is any way to change that to a different color...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write selectors for your textview using which you can change the appearance of your textview when it is selected.
You can refer to this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html